# Finding the partial derivative of a function which contains a single variable function, whose parameter is itself a multivariable function.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Say I have the function $f(x,y) = x^2g(y + ln(x))$, where $g$ is a function of a single variable. Then I let $h(x,y) = y + ln(x)$, which leaves me with the triple-nested function $f(x,y) = x^2g(h(x,y))$.

In order to find the partial derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$, I understand that I'd most likely need to use a combination of the product and chain rule, but the result I get gives me the incorrect result of the original question I'm trying to solve. I have that

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 2xg(h)) + x^2\frac{d g}{d h}\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}$,

Where $h$ is a function of $x$ and $y$, $g$ is a function of $h$ and $f$ is a function of $x$ and $y$.

Which gives me

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 2xg(h)) + x\frac{d g}{d h}$,

Since $\frac{\partial h}{\partial x} = \frac{1}{x}$.

But apparently this is incorrect. I'd like to know where the error in my reasoning is.

Comment: In the second term, you want to have $x^2\cdot g^{\prime}(h(x,y))\cdot\frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: Ahh that was a typo, I meant to write $\frac{d g}{d h}$. Fixed now.

Comment: This should give you an answer of $2xg(y+\ln x)+xg^{\prime}(y+\ln x)$

Comment: @user84413 And similarly with $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ should I get $g(y + ln x) + x^2g'(y + ln x)$? I'm being asked to show that $xf_{x} - f_{y} = kf(x,y)$ for some constant k, but so far I'm getting a non-constant result $xf_{x} - f_{y} = 2f(x,y) - g(y + ln x)$.

Comment: $f_{y}=x^2g^{\prime}(y+\ln x)$, so that should give you the result you want.

Comment: Oh of course, thanks for your help.